# how to run background service forever in android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the wallpaper according to the time set by the user, it is working fine for any long time when I run it on the emulator and also on mobile by connecting it through USB. But when I generated Signed apk and installing on it the same mobile it is not working, the app is terminating after some while.

Can anyone help me, please?

This is my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".WllPaper" />
    <service android:name=".MyThreadOne"
        android:enabled="true"/>
    <receiver android:name=".SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="ac.in.ActivityRecongnition.RestartSensor"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".NewThreadClass"/>
    <activity android:name=".NewWallpaper"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Comment: Let me know if my comment below solves your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no guarantee that work will continue in the background on Android anymore. Different OEM's treat background work differently see here for a list. https://dontkillmyapp.com/ Some googling will show you what is possible with Android as of right now. Just expect that NOTHING will behave exactly how you would like it to. I have had the most success with `WorkManager`.

You could use `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager` perhaps to achieve your desired results. But what you should be using is `WorkManager` an abstraction of both depending on Android version.

`WorkManager` is highly configurable and will allow you to create a `PeriodicWorkRequest` or a `OneTimeWorkRequest` these are guaranteed to succeed. `PeriodicWorkRequest` will fire when you schedule the work, as well as when you have specified in the timer. It will execute in the background even if the app is closed or backgrounded. If you didn't want your task to execute immediately you can use a PWR(PeriodicWorkRequest) with a [FlexInterval](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%2520extends%2520androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%2520long,%2520java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%2520long,%2520java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). See the docs below for more info.

[WorkManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)

[WorkManager Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

[WorkmManager CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0)

For example, I created two PeriodicWorkRequests that refresh services and keeps the user logged in always by renewing their token. When the user authenticates the `PeriodicWorkRequest` is created. In my case, I didn't need it to fire right away as they have just received and cached this information so I utilized the FlexInterval. When the app is backgrounded or closed, the workers continue to refresh services every 12 hours and refresh the token every 6. It works like a charm.

Here is an example:

**Build Work:**

```
 override fun beginWork() {

        val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                MyWorker::class.java,
                REPEAT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES, // How often work should repeat
                // Flex not required.
                FLEX_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // Limits execution into a time window
                .setConstraints(
                     Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(
                                       NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
                .addTag(MY_WORKER_TAG)
                .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                MY_UNIQUE_WORK,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                periodicLoginRequest)
```

**Worker:**

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
            // DO WORK HERE

            Result.success()
        } else {
            // HANDLE FAILURE HERE
            Result.failure()
        }
```

The above is a simple implementation, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: is there any possibility to know how many times the fun doWork method has been executed?

Comment: There are many ways I would imagine. If you were running this in the background you would have to persist this count to storage whether that be shared preferences or a database, or even writing a file to disk. If it is a foreground job you could save the state through an interface or presentation data or something.

Comment: If this helps you be sure to mark this as the answer.

Comment: yeah, but i want it execute a particular number of times and start over from the beginning.can you help me out with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "start over from the beginning?

Comment: I have an array List , every time the doWork method executes it should take a value from the list and do some operation, if all values are completed it should start from the first value again!!

Comment: I am trying to execute this under onClick method instead of onCreate method, it is executing even if i don't click the button after running, and i set up the time interval as 20 mins but it is executing several times in the that time. what is my mistake might be? thanks in advance

Comment: You need a flex interval as stated above ^. As to your array list that is outside the scope of this question really, but you would just select the next item every time your job fires.

Comment: Now since this answered your initial question, be sure to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android no longer allows arbitrary background services. You need to mark it as a foreground service in your manifest.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Alternatively, you might be able to use AlarmManager to build this behavior.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

Try implimanting  job service class ,which will run for lifetime in background